# how to create collapsible/expandable/ Tree structure with checkbox list using angular 6 & bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying for the collapsible/tree structure with CheckBoxs on both parent and child nodes. I haven't been able to create it exactly. I was able to create until unordered list from the JSON

```
{
  "properties": {
    "host": {
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "information": {
      "properties": {
        "filetype": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "author": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "authorcountry": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    },
    "url": {
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "name": {
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "instrument": {
      "properties": {
        "Style": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "instrumentCode": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "instrumentName": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "instrumentNumber": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

**.html code**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getData()">getData</button>


<h1>ul element</h1>

<hr>

 <ul class="list-group"   *ngFor="let x of inf | keyvalue">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{x.key}}</li>
    <ng-container *ngIf="x.value.hasOwnProperty('properties')">
      <ul *ngFor="let y of x.value.properties | keyvalue">
      <li>
        {{y.key}}
      </li>
      </ul>  
    </ng-container> 
  </ul>
```

collapsible /tree structure.

Below is my Stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k5tdpe

I can try plugins also, but the input data format for the plugins was different angular2-tree plugin & ng2 -tree /ngx-tree, so any suggestions...

[image: tree structure]

Comment: While it may seem concise to use property names as values, it becomes much more difficult to do anything with them.  I suggest you consider a single, consistent javascript structure for each node of your tree.  `{name: "mynode", data: "whatever", children: [{name: "mychild", data: "stuff"},{name: "mychild2",data: "Stuff2"}]}`

Comment: @James can i convert my existing data in to that  format and if so it is possible for u create an sample with my existing json data. Ichecked the ng-tree also as required same format my entire web site is using the above json format so only for this i need to a get diff format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add a input type check and use [(ngModel)]

```
<ul class="list-group"   *ngFor="let x of inf | keyvalue">
    <li class="list-group-item">
     <!--add a input type checkbox and relation with x.check-->
     <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="x.check">
     {{x.key}}</li>
    <!---change the *ngIf to add the x.check condition-->
    <ng-container *ngIf="x.check && x.value.hasOwnProperty('properties')">
      <ul *ngFor="let y of x.value.properties | keyvalue">
      <li>
        {{y.key}}
      </li>
      </ul>  
    </ng-container> 
  </ul>
```

***Updated***
if you want a "recursive component" its easy. I put an example, you can see the result in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpyve9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Basically a "recursive component is a component that in template has the same component. Typically we use a json model with properties children (yes, you can transform your "complex" json in some that has properties an children) If one time you create a jsondata with children, your json is like, e.g. like

```
data = [{
    title: "uno", children: [
      { title: "uno-uno" }]
  },
  {
    title: "dos", children: [
      { title: "dos-uno",children: [
           { title: "dos-uno" }
           ]},
      { title: "dos-dos" }]
  }
  ]
```

We can have a app.component like

```
  <li *ngFor="let item of data">
     <app-li [title]="item.title" [children]="item.children"></app-li>
  </li>
```

And our app-li like

```
<li (click)="check=!check">
      <div [className]="children?check?'arrow-down':'arrow-up':'arrow-right'"></div>
      {{title}}
</li>
<ul *ngIf="children && check">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of children">
       <app-li [title]="item.title" [children]="item.children"></app-li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

See that we feed the app-li with "children"

NOTE:I add a < div> with className to "simulate" the triangles

**Updated 2**
We can pass the own item itselft

The component becomes like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-li',
  template: `<li >
              <div (click)="check=!check" [className]="item.children?
                   check?'arrow-down':'arrow-up':'arrow-right'">
              </div>
              <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.select" >
              <span (click)="check=!check">{{item.title}}</span>
              </li>
             <ul *ngIf="item.children && check">
             <ng-container *ngFor="let item of item.children">
               <app-li [item]="item" ></app-li>
               </ng-container>
             </ul>
  `,
    styleUrls: [ './hello.component.css' ]



})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() item: any;
}
```

And the app

```
<li *ngFor="let item of data">
     <app-li [item]="item" ></app-li>
</li>
```

See [stackblitz forked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-micjnf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: could u help me out with this changes in stack blitz & how can i get the click functionalities also ?

Comment: just replace the code, you can see in your forked stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpyve9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: actually this i made but the internal children also has to be gets selected along with parent we may have n number of children whatever we select the value along with parent that particular childern has to be selected and along with the likeparent suppose if information parent has to no children then i have to get "information" as value if "information" has children and what ever children we select that values have to come like Information,information.child1,information.child2 values  and like the image which uploaded in question

Comment: @Madpop, I updated my answer to make a "recursive component". Your .json is too complex. I suggest you, to change it for some more "simple" (perhafs you can transform the example of recursive component using your json -I'm lazy to do it-)

Comment: can we insert checkbox in that ?

Comment: In this case is better pass the own item, see updated 2 response