# how to apply check boxes for parent and children in angular & bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

here what my requirement is :-

**when ever i click on the parent its child elements has also get selected and in that also we can deselect  what ever we dont want. And on button click the  we have to get the selected parent & children names  as 
 object**

what i did till now :-

i created a list of parents and children and supplied checkbox for the parent and getting the parents values after check n uncheck and getting the value

im stuck how can i select the children in that parent and get values of both parent and children

below is my code

.ts

```
 @ViewChildren('myItem') item;
  selectedIds = [];
 display:any;
 data:any;

  ngOnInit(){


    // dynamic json 

    this.data = {
  "info": {
    "laptop": {
    },
    "config": {
      "properties": {
        "ram": {
        },
        "processor": {
        },
        "hdd": {

        }
      }
    },
    "link": {

    },
    "name": {

    },
    "company": {
      "properties": {
        "model": {

        },
        "maker": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "enterprise": {

        }

      }
    }
  }
};


  // varible 

    this.display = this.data['info'];
    console.log(this.display);

  }

  change(data,event){
 if (event.target.checked === true) {
      this.selectedIds.push({id: data, checked: event.target.checked});
      console.log('Selected data ', JSON.stringify(this.selectedIds));
    }
    if (event.target.checked === false) {
      this.selectedIds = this.selectedIds.filter((item) => item.id !== data);
    }


}
getData(){
      const filtered = this.selectedIds.filter(item => item.id)
 console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
    }
```

.html code

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let parent of display | keyvalue">
  <li class="list-group-item">  <input  type="checkbox" [value]="parent.key" [(ngModel)]="parent.check"  #myItem  (change)="change(parent.key,$event)">{{parent.key}}</li>
 <ng-container *ngIf="parent.check && parent.value.hasOwnProperty('properties')">
      <ul *ngFor="let child of parent.value.properties | keyvalue">
      <li>
        {{child.key}}
      </li>
      </ul>  
    </ng-container> 
</ul>

<hr>

<button class="btn btn-primary"(click)="getData()">get Data</button>
```

my stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vqwsc

[image: parent and child]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing you need is pass to your function the "children"

```
(change)="change(parent.key,parent.value.properties,$event)"
```

then in your function change becomes like

```
  change(data, children, event) {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      this.selectedIds.push({ id: data, checked: event.target.checked });
      for (let child in children) {
        this.selectedIds.push({ id: child, checked: event.target.checked });
      }
    }
    if (event.target.checked === false) {
      this.selectedIds = this.selectedIds.filter((item) => item.id !== data);
      for (let child in children) {
        this.selectedIds = this.selectedIds.filter((item) => item.id !== child);
      }
    }
```

There are a problem that is show the selected values. For this you need make a function

```
  isChecked(child) {
    let item = this.selectedIds.find(x => x.id == child.key)
    return item ? item.checked : false
  }
```

And add (click) to the "children" to change the this.selected

```
  <ul *ngFor="let child of parent.value.properties | keyvalue">
  <li>
    <input  type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked(child)" (change)="change(child.key,null,$event)"/>
    {{child.key}}
  </li>
  </ul>
```

But I think that there're a better way to do the things. Imagine that your data becomes

```
this.data2 =[ 
  {
    "id":"laptop","checked":false
    },
    {"id":"config","checked":false,"properties": [
        {"id":"ram","checked":false},
        {"id":"processor","checked":false},
        {"id":"ram","checked":false}
      ]
    },
    {"id":"link","checked":false},
    {"id":"name","checked":false},
    {"id":"company","checked":false,"properties":[
        {"id":"model","checked":false},
        {"id":"maker","checked":false},
        {"id":"country","checked":false},
        {"id":"enterprise","checked":false}

    ]}
]
```

(I put checked property, but it's not necesary)
Your .html becomes easer

```
<ul *ngFor="let parent of data2">
  <li><input  type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="parent.checked" (change)="changedChild(parent.checked,parent.properties)"> {{parent.id}}
      <ng-container *ngIf="parent.checked">
        <ul  *ngFor="let child of parent.properties">
      <li>
        <input  type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="child.checked" />
        {{child.id}}
      </li>
      </ul>  
      </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the function changedChild

```
changedChild(value,children)
{
   if (children)
       children.forEach(x=>x.checked=value)
}
```

**Updated** adding object to this.selectedChild
the functions becomes

```
change(data, children, event) {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      this.selectedIds.push({ id: data, checked: event.target.checked });
      for (let child in children) {
        this.selectedIds[this.selectedIds.length-1][child]=event.target.checked;

      }
    }
    if (event.target.checked === false) {
      this.selectedIds = this.selectedIds.filter((item) => item.id !== data);
    }

}
changeChild(parentKey,childKey,event)
{
    let item:any = this.selectedIds.find(x => x.id == parentKey)
    if (event.target.checked)
      item[childKey]=event.target.checked;
    else
      delete item[childKey];

}

isChecked(parentKey,childKey) {
    let item:any = this.selectedIds.find(x => x.id == parentKey)
    return item ? item[childKey] : false
  }
```

And the html

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let parent of display | keyvalue">
  <li class="list-group-item">  <input  type="checkbox" [value]="parent.key" [(ngModel)]="parent.check"  #myItem  (change)="change(parent.key,parent.value.properties,$event)">{{parent.key}}</li>
 <ng-container *ngIf="parent.check && parent.value.hasOwnProperty('properties')">
      <ul *ngFor="let child of parent.value.properties | keyvalue">
      <li>
         <input  type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked(parent.key,child.key)" (change)="changeChild(parent.key,child.key,$event)"/>
    {{child.key}}

      </li>
      </ul>  
    </ng-container> 
</ul>
```

See [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8j4enk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: i applied your logic in my stackblitz  getting unable to get target values error in console  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vqwsc

Comment: You forget send the childs in the (change) of outer loop < input  type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="parent.checked":(change)="change(parent.key, **parent.value.properties** ,$event)

Comment: ok got it a small issue when i am trying to get the value i am getting the values as individual elements  like below    [{"id":"company","checked":true},{"id":"model","checked":true},{"id":"maker","checked":true},{"id":"country","checked":true},{"id":"enterprise","checked":true},{"id":"config","checked":true},{"id":"ram","checked":true},{"id":"processor","checked":true},{"id":"hdd","checked":true}]          so here i cant recognise which child belong to which parent or  which parent have how many childs

Comment: How you want stored? If you want, you can make selectedId have a propertiy "children", but remember that, in check of children you must pass as argument the parent (to find it in this.selectedItems), the child and if is checked or not -the function must be diferent in one check or in another. What about change the "json"?

Comment: if selected ex:- company has 4 properties so company.prop1, company.prop2  if laptop have no property then laptop key has to be selected

Comment: all the selected has to be in one object in that prop.child if prop has no child the  only prop name has be selected

Comment: I updated my answer: You must have two function "change" and "changeChild", the function "isChecked" change too

Comment: How can i get filter option in the tree structure instead of going all through i can filter

Comment: first of all you can take my second option. It's easy, it's like your another question. You can see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aflqod?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. After you can use *ngIf in .html

Comment: one last doubt we have mentioned change function in the parent element and at present im  using get data for getting the values so instead i thought after checking can we get the  values ? but there is already a change function is there

Comment: what sort  of modification is needed if we have parent -> child->child some n levels ?

Comment: puff. You need make some recursive (in functións and in component). You can start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685156/how-to-create-collapsible-expandable-tree-structure-with-checkbox-list-using-an/53686454#53686454 to make the component recursive. But remember that functións must be recursive too