# create nested drop down menu of parent child data

Tags: html, css, angular, drop-down-menu, nested

I want to generate nested items for my dropdown based on received data from API with the parent-child structure.
I have a form for creating a user and in this form, I have dropdown select that
its data is about organization units that have a parent-child relationship for each ou.
my admin is obfuscating when he wants to create a user because of the ou's show in linear mode and wants to show these ous in nested view can you help me?
my data structure is :

```
export class DisplayOu {
    id: number;
    parentId: number;
    name: string;
    cssClass: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    designation: number;
    subordinates: DisplayOu[] = []
}
```

Comment: What are you supposed to do by creating the sub class of same class?

Comment: @Iswar for showing ous in tree view

Comment: you're looking for a recursive component. It's easy, take a look, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305905/how-can-i-create-a-nested-recursive-table-that-can-drill-down-x-levels-in-angul/55315414#55315414, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376237/create-tree-view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-showing-the-connectivity-usi/56381812#56381812 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685156/how-to-create-collapsible-expandable-tree-structure-with-checkbox-list-using-an/53686454#53686454 or use material tree-view https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue from what I have analysed from your problem. I have noticed that you are creating array object of `DisplayOu` in the same class. I have fixed using different interface for parent menu and sub menu like this:

```
interface  MainMenu {
   id: number;
   parentId: number;
   name: string;
   cssClass: string;
   imageUrl: string;
   designation: number;
   subMenus:SubMenu[];
}
interface  SubMenu {
   id: number;
   parentId: number;
   name: string;
   cssClass: string;
   imageUrl: string;
   designation: number;
}
```

For getting the data I have created const object (in your case it is result from API) like this:

```
    const menu: MainMenu[] = [
      {
        id: 1,
        cssClass: "foo",
        designation: 3,
        imageUrl: "",
        name: "John",
        parentId: 1,
        subMenus: [
          {
            id: 2,
            cssClass: "foo",
            designation: 3,
            imageUrl: "",
            name: "Loream Ipsum 1",
            parentId: 1
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            cssClass: "foo",
            designation: 3,
            imageUrl: "",
            name: "Loream Ipsum 2",
            parentId: 1
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            cssClass: "foo",
            designation: 3,
            imageUrl: "",
            name: "Loream Ipsum 3 ",
            parentId: 1
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            cssClass: "foo",
            designation: 3,
            imageUrl: "",
            name: "Loream Ipsum 4",
            parentId: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        cssClass: "foo",
        designation: 3,
        imageUrl: "",
        name: "Andy",
        parentId: 1,
        subMenus: [
          {
            id: 7,
            cssClass: "foo",
            designation: 3,
            imageUrl: "",
            name: "Loream Ipsum 5",
            parentId: 1
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            cssClass: "foo",
            designation: 3,
            imageUrl: "",
            name: "Loream Ipsum 6",
            parentId: 1
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            cssClass: "foo",
            designation: 3,
            imageUrl: "",
            name: "Loream Ipsum 7",
            parentId: 1
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            cssClass: "foo",
            designation: 3,
            imageUrl: "",
            name: "Loream Ipsum 8",
            parentId: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

And initialised in component like this:

```
  menuItem: MainMenu[];
  constructor() {
    this.menuItem = menu;
    console.log(this.menuItem);
  }
```

Then in `html` just displayed like this:

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown *ngFor="let menu of menuItem">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href (click)="false" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-controls="navbarDropdown" dropdownToggle>
                {{menu.name}} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" *dropdownMenu role="menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li *ngFor="let subMenu of menu.subMenus">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{subMenu.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The working [stackblitz demo is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-bootstrap4-navbar-edkjx8?file=src/app/app.component.html). I hope this helps you.

Comment: your model is a limited nested item but the depth of my tree is unlimited